# Ionic CORS issue with JIRA API

Tags: ionic-framework, cors, ionic3, jira, jira-rest-api

Problem description : I have built a ionic app which uses JIRA rest api to fetch issue (GET data), create issue (POST data). I always get CORS error's like `preflight request did not succeed or same origin policy` which are expected when we use ionic serve but the same is not working when I build and  release the signed apk.

My ionic server runs on localhost:8100 (ionic version -4) &
Jira server runs on localhost:8089 (JIRA version - core 7)

What I have done so far :
followed the proxy approach as mentioned in ionic blog --No success

enabled CORS filter plugin in JIRA server and whitelisted ionic server --No success

Added headers for Allow control origin -- No success

Build the apk file using --prod release signed and tried the same on device --No sucess

Here is my auth.ts file reference if any-one can help and advise here about what I am doing wrong here.

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { AuthProvider } from '../auth/auth';

import { Issue } from '../../models/issue'

@Injectable()
export class JiraProvider {

  apiVersion: string = '2'; // The API version we want to use
  jiraInstanceUrl: string = 'http://localhost:8089' // The Jira instance URL
  urlString: string = `${this.jiraInstanceUrl}/rest/api/${this.apiVersion}`; // Concat those together

  constructor(
    public http: HttpClient,
    public auth: AuthProvider
  ) {
  }

  // Authenticate the user against Jira's profile endpoint.
  public authenticateUser(username: string, password: string): Observable<Object> {

    return this.http.get(`${this.urlString}/myself`, {
      headers: new HttpHeaders()
        .append('Authorization', `Basic ${btoa(username + ':' + password)}`)
        .append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*")
    });
  }

  // Get issue details based on the provided key.
  public getIssue(key: string): Observable<Issue> {
    return this.http.get<Issue>(`${this.urlString}/issue/${key}`, {
      headers: new HttpHeaders()
        .append('Authorization', `Basic ${this.auth.getAuthString()}`)
        .append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*")
    });
  }

  public getAllIssue():Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.urlString}/search?jql=project=PM`,{
      headers: new HttpHeaders()
        .append('Authorization', `Basic ${this.auth.getAuthString()}`)
        .append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*")
    });
  }

  public postIssue(data):Observable<any>{
    return this.http.post(`${this.urlString}/issue`,JSON.stringify(data),{
      headers: new HttpHeaders()
        .append('Authorization', `Basic ${this.auth.getAuthString()}`)
        .append('Content-Type','application/json')
        .append("X-Atlassian-Token", "no-check")
        .append("User-Agent", "xx")
        .append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*")
    });
  }
}
```

[image]
Added screenshot as per request(please not I changed the JIRA server intentionally to 8089 updated the question accordingly)

Comment: Could you add screenshot from the Developer tools console ?

Comment: @Sescudero added screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I soved this issue by using a CORS proxy in a container (Docker) for when you need to Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`! this acts like a proxy https://github.com/imjacobclark/cors-container and now I am able to route the requests.
Hope it helps others !!